# Hiding and showing element on the basis of value in array

Tags: php, jquery

I have a menubar
`<a href="menu1" ">Menu1</a> <a href="menu2"">Menu 2</a>`
 for these menu 1 and menu2 i have stored value 0110 and so on.
I have one table where I am storing value one and ZERO for these items .
on other page I am fetching all fields in an array

```
for($i=1;$i<15;$i++)
    echo $check1[$i];
```

and getting 1010100 exactly as in database.now i want to check if value is 1 that particular menu should be displayed on page otherwise not. 
Now I want to make a jquery or using php hiding elements having value 0 and showing elements having 1 value . can i use

```
for(var i=0;var i<15;i++)
{ 
    switch (var[i]){
        case 1:var[i].hide;
            break;
        case 2:var[i].show;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: @tereško:  my question is i want to hide the menu item if its corresponding value in array is zero and show if its value is 1.Please help . I think I will have to call jquery function for all elements but how to do that i dont know.Thank you

Comment: That is not a question. It is a requirement. And that provides no information about what have you tried.

Comment: @tereško:I think you did not check question properly . Initially i tried a code for(var i=0;var i<15;i++)
{ 
    switch (var[i]){
        case 1:var[i].hide;
            break;
        case 2:var[i].show;
    }
}
and asked can i do this is it a proper way .Thank you for your response and help

Answer (score 1):

You want to toggle 1 and 0?
Check this code:

```
    <script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
    <table width="300" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
      <tr>
        <td>Index</td>
        <td>1 / 0</td>
      </tr>
      <? for($i=1;$i<15;$i++){
        $value = rand(0,1);
      ?>
      <tr class="tr<?=$value;?>">
        <td><?=$i;?></td>
        <td><?=$value;?></td>
      </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
    <a href="#" onclick="$('.tr0').show();$('.tr1').hide();">Show 0</a>
    |
    <a href="#" onclick="$('.tr1').show();$('.tr0').hide();">Show 1</a>

|
<a href="#" onclick="$('.tr1').show();$('.tr0').show();">Show both</a>
```

Comment: <a href="menu1" onclick="$('.tr0').show();$('.tr1').hide();">Menu1</a>
    <a href="menu2"onclick="$('.tr1').show();$('.tr0').hide();">Menu 2</a>  for these menu 1 and menu2 i have stored value 0110 and so on.now i want to check if value is 1 that particular menu should be displayed on page otherwise not. Thank you for your answer